# Stream Itunes library to Windows Phone

Tags: 8.1, wifi, streaming, phone-connector-mac

I have a large library of music in my laptop wich is a mac. I also have a lumia 920 and I would love to stream my Itunes library via Wi-Fi to mi Lumia. 
Ie. I wan't to play the library from my laptop in my phone via wi-fi.

Is there any solution to that problem?

Thanks

Comment: You mean bluetooh?

Comment: And did you research streaming music apps for the Mac by searching on Google first?